Looking for a Reference for the Notion of a "Connectology"
I remember at one point reading about a set of axioms characterizing the family of connected subsets of space $X$ to obtain the concept of a "connectedness space" or "connectology", analogously to the ideas of a topological space/topology of open sets.
A few of the axioms that I remember were:

Every singleton is connected.
The union of a family of connected sets with nonempty intersection is connected.

But there were four of five axioms in total.
In my own searches, I've been unable to find a reference to this idea. Can someone find a specific source (academic or otherwise) containing this concept?

https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/connectology

@DavidGao If you post this as an answer, I will upvote + accept it.

Site policy does not allow an answer that’s just a link, I believe, so I can’t really post this as an answer. It already solved your question anyway, so I don’t think it matters much.
